# How to match string with my regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String which will be coming in this format -

```
/pep/v1/clients/clientId/tester
```

I need to validate my string with the above format and extract `clientId` from it

Sample example can be -

```
/pep/v1/clients/ST-980/tester
/pep/v1/clients/123/tester
/pep/v1/clients/Hello%20World/tester
```

So `clientId` in general can be anything so I need to match whatever is there in `clientId`. It can be numbers, strings, or number and string mixture or alphanumeric strings.

So I came up with below regular expressions but it didn't worked on all the above examples.

```
^/pep/v1/clients/[0-9A-Za-z]+/tester$
```

I am working with Java, after matching my string with above regular expressions, I need to extract clientId from it.

Comment: `0-9A-Za-z]+` does not include the `-` character

Comment: Nor does it include the % character.

Comment: Why do you require a regex for this? Can do a substring between last and second last '/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"^\\/pep\\/v1\\/clients\\/(.+)\\/tester$"` will do what you need.

Note that you have to escape the `/` with `\` and since `\` is the escape character in Java you have to escape that as well, thus the `\\/` matches `/` literally.

[Here is a link to how you can experiment with it.](https://regex101.com/r/lH8nN8/2)

`^` assert position at start of a line
`\/` matches the character `/` literally
`pep` matches the characters `pep` literally (case sensitive)
`\/` matches the character `/` literally
`v1` matches the characters `v1` literally (case sensitive)
`\/` matches the character `/` literally
`clients` matches the characters `clients` literally (case sensitive)
`\/` matches the character `/` literally
1st Capturing group `(.+)`
    `.+` matches any character (except newline)
    Quantifier: `+` Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
`\/` matches the character `/` literally
`tester` matches the characters tester literally (case sensitive)

*replace the `(.+)` with `([^\\/]+)` if you want to reject ids that have a `/` literal in them.*

Comment: Thanks Jarrod so this means `.+` will match anything for clientId except newline right?

Comment: I do not think you need escape `/`

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regular expression:

```
^\/pep\/v1\/clients\/([^\/]+)\/tester$
```

Java regex would be,

```
^/pep/v1/clients/([^/]+)/tester$
```

Then print the group index 1 inorder to get your desired output.
It uses a char class with the `/` character negated, so something like `foo/bar` wouldn't be accepted in the match group.

```
String[] arr =  {"/pep/v1/clients/ST-980/tester",
        "/pep/v1/clients/123/tester",
        "/pep/v1/clients/Hello%20World/tester" };
for (String s: arr)
{
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^/pep/v1/clients/([^/]+)/tester$").matcher(s);
    while(m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ST-980
123
Hello%20World
```

Comment: When you are accepting everything except `/`, you allow stuffs like `abc?key=value` to go through, which is no longer part of the path, though I don't know whether the OP has passed the string through URL/URI class to extract the path or not. (I am not the downvoter, though)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^\\/pep\\/v1\\/clients\\/(.+)\\/tester$
```

The `.` will match any character.

Comment: I tried using this regex in `https://www.regex101.com/` but it didn't match anything?

Comment: @AKIWEB - that is because it is incorrect, see my answer.

Comment: If this is Java you want to escape / characters with \\ (two backslashes enables the string to recognize the escape of the forward slash)

Answer (score -1):

The following code would do the trick. This is assuming the rest of the suffix and prefix are constant.

```
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^/pep/v1/clients/(.+)/tester$");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher("/pep/v1/clients/ST-980/tester");
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("clientId = " + m.group(1));
    }
```